# LDAP Active directory

Tags: ldap, openldap, active

Necesito probar una conexion de LDAP pero no tengo instalado ningun servidor LDAP, en vez de instalamerlo es posible que exista alguno público en el que puedo probar, crear usuarios y roles?

Comment: Suena estupido pero has buscado en google?

Comment: es posible que no este buscando con las palabras correctas que no encuentro nada

Comment: Googleando un poco he encontrado el siguiente enlace. A ver si te sirve de algo (aunque por lo que dice sólo permite leer) https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

Comment: Tal y como dice @xero399 esta ese enlace ( el primero que hay) pero como era de 2014 no lo puse, no se nada sobre el tema de tu pregunta pero con una simple "online ldap test server" tienes varios enlaces

Comment: investigo, creo q esos datos de conexion solo es para probar pero no me permite crear usuarios ni roles

Comment: efectivamente solo me permite consultar pero no crear ya que no tengo privilegios